# Is there a way to do this keybinding in Visual studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

i recently switch from Sublime text to Vs code.
i want to do add my sublime text keyboard shorcut for " < " and " > " by modify the keybinding.json

This is what i have tried :

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "<"} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ">"} }]
```

but not working in Vs code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keybinding.json file, this should work:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+j",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": "<" }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": ">" }
}
```

Comment: And I was going to suggest  a snippet with a prefix of `<` that would insert a `<`.  LOL